# Sorting Array Returns Array Out of Order

Tags: arrays, node.js, sorting, promise, fs

I'm so confused right now. I'e spent the last hour and a bit trying to sort directories based on their creation date. Here is where I'm at:

```
const
  fsPromises = require('fs').promises
let
  arr = []

fsPromises.readdir(rootPath, 'utf8')
.then((array)=>{

  array.forEach((dir)=>{
    console.log(dir) // executed last for some reason
    fsPromises.stat(`./Projects/${dir}`)
    .then((stats)=>{
      arr.push([stats.birthtimeMs, dir])
    })
  })

})
.then(()=>{
  arr = arr.sort((a,b)=>{
    Math.floor(a[0])-Math.floor(b[0])
  })
})
.then(console.log(arr))
```

I have no idea why the final `then` is spitting out an unordered array.

Promises are new to me, so I'm not entirely sure if it's the promise chain that's causing the issue, but everything seems good up until the second `then`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try adding the `console.log(arr))` inside the first `.then`

Comment: The final `.then()` should be printing `undefined`, not an array. And you should see its output before anything else.

Comment: @mph85 The problem with sticking a `console.log` inside the first `then` is that `fsPromises.stat` is asynchronous as well. I'm completely new to Node, Electron, FS, and Promises, so this is really throwing me for a loop :(

Comment: @PatrickRoberts oh shit, sorry. in my code i have `let arr = []`, and youre right that its running first for some reason. isnt the whole purpose of promises to run the `thens` sequentially?

Comment: @BugWhisperer you're not passing a function to `.then()`. The argument should be a function.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts even if i turn the last `then` into a function (i.e. `.then(()=>{console.log(arr)})`, it still seemingly executes first out of the whole chain?

Comment: @BugWhisperer you are not waiting for the promises created inside the loop. You should group them and wait for them to finish in a Promise.all. After that, your then will have correct values.

Comment: @HarryJoy im using `fs.promises` tho? does `fs.promises` have a `promise.all`?

Comment: I guess they are returning promises at the end so you should be able to use `Promise.all` on them without any issues. Try it.

Comment: @HarryJoy i have no idea how `promise.all` works. im completely new promises. never used em at all before stumbling upon `fs.promises` lol:(

Comment: Before this line `array.forEach((dir)=>{` have an array defined `let promises = [];`. Now inside the loop, push your fsPromises call inside this array. Something like `promises.push(fsPromises.stat(./Projects/${dir}).then(......))` and at the end, ourtside of loop, `return Promise.all(promises)`. Just a psuedo code, if any syntax errors, please check the official document.

Comment: Check @amadan's answer, he has done some Promise.all magic.

Comment: @HarryJoy what confuses me even more about this whole thing is that im running asynchronous code and synchronous code, and desired order of execution is something like: asynchronous code > (wait for completion) > synchronous code that executes a multitude of threads of asynchronous code (each of which call synchronous code) > (wait for completion of synchronous code from all asynchronous threads) > synchronous code -- at which point is should be done. -- i just realized there were multiple comments, which i havent read yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the promise chain: if the chain is broken anywhere, it won't work.

You seem to be mixing up the two arrow forms: `(params) => expression` and `(params) => { statements }`. Everything in your code is expressible with the former, so I went with that. If you convert to the statement block form, do not forget to `return` (which the expression form does implicitly).

Because you don't return the promises from the arrow statement block, the next promise is not stitched to the previous one, so there is no waiting going on and things execute much more synchronously than intended. Additionally, if you have multiple promises, you need to wait till they are all ready to fulfill by using `Promise.all`. It will create a promise that all the sub-promises are done, and return an array of results of sub-promises.

```
fsPromises.readdir(rootPath, 'utf8')
.then(array => Promise.all(
    array.map(dir =>
        fsPromises.stat(`./Projects/${dir}`)
        .then(stats => [stats.birthtimeMs, dir])
    )
))
.then(arr =>
  arr.sort((a, b) =>
    Math.floor(a[0]) - Math.floor(b[0])
  )
)
.then(arr => console.log(arr))
```

(I did not check this, so there might be accidental dragons.)

So first `readdir` promises an array of files. We will map this array so that for each filename, `stat` makes a promise of its stats, and we chain it into a promise of tuples. So `array.map` now returns an array of tuple promises. `Promise.all` receives the array of promises, and promises an array of results of those promises when they are all done. We chain this into a promise of a sorted array, then chain it into a promise of console logging the array.

EDIT: <strike>I am not sure, but I don't think `Promise.all` exists in Node.js core. There is any number of promise packages for Node.js that do include `Promise.all`, pretty much any of them will do (e.g. [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html)). Or, you could [implement it yourself](https://dev.to/ycmjason/how-to-implement-promiseall-4k81), it's not that big.</strike>

EDIT2: One could also suggest you switch to `async`/`await` if it's supported in your environment, as it makes code much more similar to what you are used to. However, some understanding of promises is still needed, as it's all promises under the hood. :P

```
async function statDir() {
  let files = await fsPromises.readdir(rootPath, 'utf8');
  let stats = [];
  for (let file of files) {
    let stat = await fsPromises.stat(`./Projects/${file}`);
    stats.push([stat.birthtimeMs, file]);
  }
  stats.sort((a, b) =>
    Math.floor(a[0]) - Math.floor(b[0])
  );
  console.log(stats);
}
statDir();
```

Comment: Cool. I'd probably rather implement it myself rather than include another dependency. It's probably going to take me some time to digest all of this since the whole concept of promises is very new to me and I've been staring at a screen for far too long.

Comment: Wow, `Promise.all` did work in your first example. Shouldn't it work anyways since Node is JS after all? Or Is there a reason why it wouldn't have worked?

Comment: Oh, I guess I was remembering an old version...? Or a brain fart, who knows. I guess I should delete that paragraph.

Comment: The `async await` syntax is so much more intuitive and easily understood imo. is that just due to me not being used to promises? which syntax seems more straightforward to you?

Comment: As I said, `async`/`await` was created in order to simplify the promise syntax and make it look almost like synchronous code. It is still dealing with promises though, so if you don't understand promises, it is kind of easy to mess up with `async`/`await`.

Comment: right makes sense. is there even any reason to use `fs.promises` in your second example if its essentially all `async await` promises already?

Comment: For example, I messed up in the first iteration of the `async`/`await` code: I wrote `let stats = files.map(async file => ...)`; but that is incorrect, because now `stats` contains an array of promises (since every `async` function returns a promise); the correct way to write it with `map` is `let stats = await Promise.all(async file => ...)`. So I deliberately switched to the `for` loop to avoid `Promise.all` there.

Comment: The non-promisified `fs` would use callbacks, which are not compatible with promises, and thus can't be `await`-ed.

Comment: right. thats where i was going wrong with my attempt. creating a bunch of unrelated promises. for some reason im getting the `Syntax Error: await is only valid in async function` for your 2nd example. its funny because i also tried using an IIFE and same problem. does node not support `async await`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200494/discussion-between-amadan-and-bugwhisperer).